# Returning a unique value across documents in couchDB usings views

Tags: javascript, database, view, mapreduce, couchdb

I have a series of documents each containing a date and a list of letters. I need the output to be a single, unique letter per key with the latest date for each letter as a value.

With a simple mapping function that looks like:

```
{
   "_id": "_design/output",
   "_rev": "1-c7b904b0e93709113c49127efb40187a",
   "language": "javascript",
   "views": {
       "output": {
           "map": "function(doc) {\n  emit(doc.args.report.updated_partitions, doc.timestamp);\n}",
           "reduce": "function(key, value, reduce) {\n  return (value)\n}"
       }
   }
}
```

I get the following result:

```
{"total_rows":2,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"8e561dd15fd33acfc7c4502c58008c2a","key":["a","b"],"value":1403818824},
{"id":"8e561dd15fd33acfc7c4502c5800a212","key":["a","c","d"],"value":1403818700}
]}
```

The output I'm looking for should look like:

```
{"total_rows":2,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"8e561dd15fd33acfc7c4502c58008c2a","key":["a"],"value":1403818824},
{"id":"8e561dd15fd33acfc7c4502c58008c2a","key":["b"],"value":1403818824},
{"id":"8e561dd15fd33acfc7c4502c58008c2a","key":["c"],"value":1403818824},
{"id":"8e561dd15fd33acfc7c4502c5800a212","key":["d"],"value":1403818700}
]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a simpler method. The basic steps are:

1. Map each individual letter to the date
2. Reduce the result by returning the maximum value from an array of all dates by key.

The map looks like:

```
function(doc) {
  var files = doc.args.report.updated_partitions;
  var timestamp = doc.timestamp;

  for (i=0; i<files.length; i+= 1){
    var file_name = files[i];
    emit(file_name, timestamp);
  }
}
```

And the reduce looks like:

```
function(key, value, reduce) {
  return (Math.max.apply(null, value))
}
```

The result will be a unique key for each letter with the latest date from all docs as a value.

The use case for this is when each couch document has a list of files that were modified and the date the modification took place, but you would like to know the latest modification date for each individual document.

Comment: Brilliant solution learnt something new. Thanks for posting this. I guess reduce can be used in clever ways if you give it some thought :)